# Unable to provision large VSIs on IBM Cloud with RAM>=128GB and #cpus>=32

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am unable to create large VMs on IBM Cloud, with mem >=128GB and cpus>=32. 
The error I get is it can't find the pricing.
I do set a valid combination, that works when ordering VMs via portal.
But with terraform, it states it can't find pricing for the selected configuration.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how terraform works but if you are getting a SoftLayer error then maybe I can help you, what is the exactly error message?

Comment: Could you post the terraform request that you are using.

Comment: Enable the debug and post the error to us: `TF_LOG= DEBUG terraform apply`